# Composition of a holomorphic function with a normal family of holomorphic functions.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ (open) $\subset \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ a normal family of holomorphic functions in $\Omega_1$ such that $f(\Omega_1) \subset \Omega_2$ $\forall f \in \mathcal{F}$.

We want to prove that if $\Omega_3$ is a another open subset such that $\overline{\Omega_2} \subset \Omega_3$ and $g \in \mathcal{H}(\Omega_3)$ then $g \circ \mathcal{F}$=$\{g \circ f $ $ |$ $ f \in \mathcal{F}\}$ is a normal family.

My try:

Given a sequence of functions in $g \circ \mathcal{F}$ it'd be

$\{$ $g \circ f_n$ $\}$. Also we know that $\mathcal{F}$ is normal so $\{$ $f_n$ $\}$ has a subsequence $\{$ $f_{n_k}$ $\}$ which is convergent to the holomorphic function $f$.

I want to show that $\{$g $\circ$ $f_{n_k}$ $\}$$\rightarrow$$g\circ f$

Given a compact subset $K \subset$ $\Omega_1$ and given $\epsilon >0$ i need to show  that $\exists$ $n_{k_0}$ st if $n_k \geq$ $n_{k_0}$ then

|$\{$g $\circ$ $f_{n_k}$ - $g \circ f$| $< \epsilon$ $\forall z \in K$

I want to use convergence of  $f_{n_k}$ and then use continuity of $g$ but i need uniform continuity of $g$ to make sure that it works for all $z \in K$

what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is really about controlling the images $f_n(K)$ as $n$ goes to infinity. If we can show that these sets are contained in a suitable compact subset inside $\Omega_2$, then we win by continuity of $g$.

Let's then take a sequence $g \circ f_n$ and a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ that converges uniformly to $f$ on any compact $K \subset \Omega_1$. Given such a compact set, pick an $\epsilon$ such that the $\epsilon$-neighborhood
$$
f(K)_{\epsilon} = \{ z \in \Omega_2 \mid \sup_{w \in f(K)} | z - w| \leq \epsilon \}
$$
is contained in $\Omega_3$ (which is possible because $f(K) \subset \overline{\Omega_2} \subset \Omega_3$). Note that since $f(K)$ is compact, then so is $f(K)_{\epsilon}$. By construction, since we started with a normal family, then $f_{n_k}(K) \subset f(K)_{\epsilon}$ for all $k$ big enough. But then we win, because as $g$ is continuous and $f(K)_{\epsilon}$ is compact, there exists $M > 0$ such that
$$
|g(z) - g(w)| \leq M|z-w|
$$
for all $z,w \in f(K)_{\epsilon}$. That means that
$$
|g(f_{n_k}(z)) - g(f(z))| \leq M|f_{n_k}(z)-f(z)|
$$
for all $z \in K$ for all very big $k$, and by hypothesis we can make the right-hand side as small as we want on $K$.

Comment: Why is $f(K)_{\epsilon}$ compact? The rest is clear thanks :)

Comment: Well, $f(K)$ is closed in $\Omega_3$ because it's contained in $\overline{\Omega_2}$. Then $f(K)_{\epsilon}$ is also closed in $\Omega_3$ if we take $\epsilon$ to be small enough; think of stepping a distance of $\epsilon$ away from the boundary of $f(K)$, if our step is small enough we're still in $\Omega_3$. But $f(K)_{\epsilon}$ is then closed and bounded in $\mathbb{C}$, thus compact, because it's contained in a closed ball whose radius should be clear. Then $f(K)_{\epsilon}$ is compact in $\Omega_3$, for example by the sequential criterion.

Comment: The topology of the plane may seem trivial when compared with more exotic spaces, but the more advanced subjects in complex analysis are absolutely dependent on the geometry and topology of the plane. It really helps to look for the geometry lying behind the formulas in these problems.

Comment: Please, could you recommend a book or any material to understand intuitevily or visually the geometry of these problems?